# React initial state delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React project and I am fetching data from firebase directly on the client side.
For the components that are using an initial state (which is usually set from firestore data), there is like 1 second delay on the component until the data is visible.
For example, I have a paragraph "Welcome {username}". Username is being set in the useEffect by calling a function that fetches data from firestore. At first it appears blank and after 1 second, let's say, the username is visible.
Is there anything I can do to fix this? I know it is due to the setState, but I am wondering if there is any fix.

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: The delay is caused by your browser making a request to the Firebase API. This is called **Client Side Rendering**. If you want **Server Side Rendering**, meaning your server fetches the data from Firebase on every request and then returns the HTML when it's done fetching, you should look into React frameworks such as Next.js or Gatsby.

Comment: You could render the component that holds the user only when the username is loaded like this: `username? <usernamecomponent> : <blankcomponent>`.

Or, you could fetch all the necesary data early on in the render process (say.. App.js or index.js) and there you return a placeholder while your fetching the data :

`if (datareturned) {
return (
//your actual stuff
)} else {
return (
<p>loading...</p>
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is not a fix, but a way to display things once they've been loaded.

What I would suggest is a conditional display.
Something like :

```js
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    yourMethodThatSetUsername();
  }, [])

  return (
    {
      username ? <YourComponent /> : null
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you set a state in the component from which you are calling useEffect, like this:

[loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

You can then  conditionally render your component like this:
loading ? //some progress component
: `Welcome ${username}`;